# Android WebView window.onload event issue

Tags: android, webview, onload-event

I am working on one Android App where I am loading local file contents into webview using following syntax.

```
url = "file://" + mLocalFilePath + java.io.File.separator + CURRENT_FILE;

webView.loadUrl(url);
```

The issue is the webview loads file contents  and also loads the various images from url present in webpage ( webpage has many images ).

The challenge I am facing is I want to get notified when webview finish rendering entire html page.I want to get notified when webpage is 100% loaded.

I reffered various forums and also tried using

`window.onload` function

as well as

`public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)`

But I did not get desire output,I get callback before html page is completely loaded.I am looking for way so that I will get notified only when webpage has finished rendering all the images present in web page.( i.e Webpage is 100% loaded.)

I am not looking for complete answer even hints will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: onPageFinished works well for me can u post whole code

Comment: @MT8 Cant post the code as its quite huge.But I have specified the abstract Idea on what I am doing.Do you get notified after all assets are loaded in webview ?

Comment: @vipul shah setWebChromeClient() to webview is working perfectly.

Comment: Biraj Zalavadia is posted code is that way u called?

Comment: @MT8 I tried this code but still I get callback before entire page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);

                if(newProgress==100){
                    // page loading completes
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I used deprecated `PictureListener` that start when all images on the pages are loaded. It deprecated and you need at least one image in the html but if you can manage this (you could place transparent 1px*1px image) it's a good solution.

```
    wv.setPictureListener(new PictureListener() {

        @Override
        public void onNewPicture(WebView view, Picture picture) {
            // some code here
            } 
        }
    });
```